# Can I modify RoR CRUD behavior?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know that the RoR CRUD is very easy to use. But I want the generate program do something special that normal CRUD. I don't want "Delete" in my apps, all the record only can make as "delete" instead of actually delete. So, I want to add a column -- "status" automatically when the Create is generated, and I want to change the "Delete" behavior to "Make as delete". Can I do that? if yes, how can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, try acts_as_paranoid, or [permanent_records](http://github.com/JackDanger/permanent_records), which I'm also a big fan of.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want [acts_as_paranoid](http://ar-paranoid.rubyforge.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this -> http://activescaffold.com/ can help you, is like a super powered scaffold :)